# Redirection operator priority in Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, su

This command does not work:

```
$ sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Brak dostępu
```

But when I gain root priviliges separately everything works.

```
root@pc:~# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
root@pc:~#
```

Does this have something to do with `>` operator redirecting sudo, not echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **tee**;

```
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Or you can simply run a `bash` string as `sudo`:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```